# jquery ui theme on all elements but one

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-theme

I'm using a lot of jquery ui in my page: autocomplete, dialog, datepicker, etc. I styled the theme for those elements and it's ok.

I also have a tab navigation and I would like to exclude it from the theme. I deleted all tab related ( only the ones that start with tab) css from my theme, but it's still full of jquery ui css ( widget, header, content, etc) that I cannot change because then also the other elements will change and I don't want that. I know how to apply the css scope, but it's not good for me ( it's difficult to style autocomplete and dialog with a scope theme).

Is there a way to exclude only the tabs from styling?

Thank you

Comment: override em w. something else

Comment: Its time consuming and hectic stuff to alter the jquery-ui css content,most of the time it goes wrong. moreover your page becomes unstable. avoid doing that.

Comment: why -1? a lot of people asked how to style only one element. I want to style everything but one element and I thought that someone might know a nice method. I'll try to override them. Thank you both for the answers.

Comment: Can't you define a scope only for tabs?

Comment: You're doing it wrong! LoL, no really, you're doing it wrong. Use Name-Spacing to "override" the ui css where needed. Use jQueryUI tabs but make sure you put them in a wrapper with and ID or Class name. Then just use the name before each UI CSS override. Example: `#myElement .ui-tabs-nav { padding: 0; }` Everything about jQueryUI is overridable, for this very reason.

Comment: Ok. I will do like you said. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in jQueryUI CSS is over-writable for this very reason. The key you're missing is that you're applying you're overrides directly. Or so I assume. something like:

```
.ui-widget { font-size: 42px; }
```

I know that's what they show in their docs, but it's just plain wrong when you want "specific elements" effected. For that you need to rely on [Name Spacing](http://lesscsstutorial.com/namespaces/). This means using an ID or Class Name ***you*** create before the UI Class Name You want to edit. Such as:

```
#myEleID .ui-widget { font-size: 84px; }
```

This way, only the children elements using `ui-widget` within the Element having the ID `myEleId` are affected. Nothing else on the page will be affected in any way.

To Get a better idea, I made you a fiddle with 2 sets of tabs. The first set is edited to be vertical but uses my Name Space to make the change. This way, the second set (set to default) is not effected, no matter the UI theme! You'll also find a theme switcher in the bottom of the fiddle. Try it out!

## jsFiddle

```
#tabs { 
    width: 55em; 
}
#tabs .ui-tabs-nav { 
    padding: .2em .4em .2em .2em; float: left; width: 12em; 
}
#tabs .ui-tabs-nav li { 
    clear: left; width: 100%; border-bottom-width: 1px !important; border-right-width: 0 !important; margin: 0 -1px .2em 0; 
}
#tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a { 
    display:block;
    padding: .5em 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
#tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active { 
    padding-bottom: 0; padding-right: .1em; border-right-width: 1px; border-right-width: 1px; 
}
#tabs .ui-tabs-panel { 
    padding: 1em; float: right; width: 40em;
}
```

I also wrote a blog a long while back about getting current tab in jQueryUI. It talks a little bit about name-spacing and may also be helpful on your future en devours.
http://spyk3lc.blogspot.com/2012/08/jqueryjqueryui-help-tabs-get-currently.html